# Swift textField input hh:mm as duration

Tags: ios, swift

Using the textField delegate method with:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        switch textField {
            // allow only numbers
        case picTextField, sicTextField, pax1TextField, pax2TextField, pax3TextField, pax4TextField, lhCargoTextField, aftCargoTextField, rhCargoTextField, basketTextField, hookTextField,poleTextField, fuelTextField:
            let s = NSString(string: textField.text ?? "").replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            guard !s.isEmpty else { return true }
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .none
            return numberFormatter.number(from: s)?.intValue != nil
            // allow max 4 characters
        case departureTextField, destinationTextField, alternateTextField:
            let maxLength = 4
            let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
            let newString: NSString =
                currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
            return newString.length <= maxLength
            // time formatting
        case tripTimeTextField:
                    default:
            return true
        }
```

In the case tripTimeTextField I need to limit the user input to hh:mm as a duration. I was reading through multiple posts but couldn't find the right answer. DateComponentsFormatter seems to go that direction but I couldn't figure out how to apply it.

Apple uses that format in the Alarm app in iOS 14, except there it is time and not duration. But that is pretty much what I am looking for. I know datePicker is an option but I am just not the biggest fan of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dumb implementation of such validation which can be refined further for your use case.

```swift
    func isValidHHMM(input: String) -> Bool {
        let comps = input.components(separatedBy: ":")
        
        let hhComp = comps.first ?? ""
        if hhComp.count > 2 {
            return false
        }
        let hh = Int(hhComp) ?? 0
        let hhValid = (hh < 24)
        
        guard comps.count == 2 else {
            return hhValid
        }
        
        let mmComp = comps.last ?? ""
        if mmComp.count > 2 {
            return false
        }
        let mm = Int(mmComp) ?? 0
        let mmValid = (mm < 60) 
        
        return (hhValid && mmValid)
    }
```